# sending a form email to a .cc email

Tags: php, forms, webserver, html-email

I am working on an email form.

I wondered if there was a restriction on sending php emails to email addresses such as info@domain.cc emails? The .cc is the ending url. Will this affect it?

Any help would be great.

Cheers,
mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no PHP restrictions regarding the email address formating.

You might run into some problems if you are trying to send an email to an address composed out of asian characters, for example, due to possible encoding conflicts, but otherwise you're ok.

I made a mailing script once to prank my friends with fake mails and I was able to send mails to addresses that didn't even contain ab @.

This sort of restrictions are mostly up to you, the developer. Otherwise, it would be a bad idea since you can have valid email addresses that aren't even in the username@domain.extension format.

Comment: Yes I know that as developers we have to enable some restrictions.

Comment: Then do not worry and implement only the restrictions you need (or are required to)

Comment: The problem I ma having is that all other emails I set my form to receive the message, but when I set the email address to the google mail account, it will not send it and the client does not get the email in the inbox?

Comment: can you show us the code you use for mailing? Is it made by you or do you use a script made by someone else?

Comment: Hey BBog, Here is the link to the page with the form on it http://www.startmeup.cc

Comment: No, I mean the PHP bit that actually sends the mail. Is it as simple as the examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ?

Comment: no its a bit more complex to be honest. Do you want me to send it to you in an email?

Comment: ha ha sorry. Well after much diagnosis, the form worked. I had to configure the server to get it working after all. Thanks for the help BBog.

Answer (score 1):

`info@domain.cc` looks like a well formated emails to me ...

its like ... `info@domain.eu`, no problem at all

Comment: every other email account I put in receives it well but this one does not but this email info@domain.is also does not receive the email too. They are with google apps mail?

Answer (score 1):

.cc is a valid top level domain so it should work.

The fact is, PHP can "send" mail to any email address.  Whether it gets delivered depends on whether the email address is valid.  For example, bill_gates_is_a_wanker@microsoft.com probably is not a valid email address, even though it's formatted correctly.  So PHP will try to send it and Microsoft's servers will probably respond with a "no such account" kind of error.